# Why would one use a POST-based search engine on their website?

Tags: post, web, google-analytics, get

I'm aware of the differences between GET and POST (security and caching, in particular). Additionally, when I search this question using Google, I'm only greeted by results telling me how to hack site search in Google Analytics for POST-based engines. I already know how to do that.

What I'm wondering is why employ a POST-based search engine in the first place? What are the salient advantages? I can't imagine why site search queries would need to be secure. So maybe it has something to do with caching?

Thanks so much in advance to anyone who can shed light on this.

Comment: I'd say GET queries are actually the way to go in most cases, although some specific cases (which I don't quite see here) may need POST.

Comment: I think this would be better suited for the programmers stackoverflow site (while it is about programming it is not about a specific reproducable problem). But POST is no more secure than GET (as you already found out) and Pages with POST requests are not usually cached (else they would show the same result for different inputs), so whatever reason, those two are not among them.

Comment: Programmers site? Thanks a lot for the tip (I'm new here). I'll take the question over there.

Answer (score 1):

No real "answer" to this one - it's entirely up to the site owners choice and/or the options the software they use on their website.

I would however say that there **are** very valid reasons for search terms to be secure. If you are searching for personal private medical conditions for example, or perhaps your own sexual preferences that you'd prefer not to be widely known. And then there's search terms used in more restrictive countries than you're obviously used to where having a history of those search terms on your computer could get you in very serious trouble.

[Google has long restricted search terms from being passed on to the next website in the referrer field for just the reasons](https://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html?m=1).

Advantages of a GET based search page:

- Easy to copy and paste link for someone else.
- Adds to your web history.
- Allows search engine to be implemented in client side (e.g. like Google Custom Search Engine uses with a JavaScript call to Google's main search engine rather than a complicated server side search engine implementation).

Advantages of POST based search pages are mostly to do with security:

- Cannot be accidentally shared by copying and pasting URL.
- Does not add search terms to web history
- Cannot leak search terms in referrer fields for sites you click on. This takes extra effort to do with a GET request (like Google has done) but is default with POST requests.